# Error from RemoteAuthentication: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandl er: message.State is null or empty

Tags: c#

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
/// Configures the services.
/// The services.
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

```
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
         {
         options.Authority = _configuration["AzureAD:Instance"];
         options.ClientId = _configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
         options.ClientSecret = _configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"];
       //options.ResponseType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token;
         options.ResponseType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;

         options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
         options.SaveTokens = true;
         options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
         options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
         options.CallbackPath = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString.FromUriComponent(new Uri(_configuration["AzureAD:CallbackPath"]));

             //options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
             //{
             //    IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"]))
             //};
    });

       

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

appsettings.cs
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/db54834d-59e1-4fa1-ab0c-d87e79b73e86",
"Domain": "greenergydevs.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "db54834d-59e1-4fa1-ab0c-d87e79b73e86",
"ClientId": "cbdb9e9d-f5f1-4f2c-ad5c-5e9b5d918ca5",
"CallbackPath": "https://gry75app03:9001/home/dashboard",

Comment: It looks like a client tried to connect to the service and failed.  The connection requires HTTPS (secure not http).  The authentication is performed using TLS which occurs before the request is sent from client to server.  TLS the server send a certificate block where names of certificates are sent and client then looks up in stores the certificate names.  The certificate must be loaded in the client.  Also TLS used different encryption methods and the client must be able to support the encryption mode in the certifcate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to perform the authorization code flow? if so your response type should be

```
options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
```

Also the following scope is mandatory when using OIDC

```
options.Scope.Add("openid"); //openid => always needed when working with OIDC
```

Also add following events to your handler and debug if possible, to see where it goes wrong./

```
 //Map out some of the events we can hook into during login/logout at our IDP
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                //Here we can subscribe to events which can happen in the chain of events when authenticating against the IDP
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenResponseReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnUserInformationReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTicketReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAccessDenied = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnRemoteSignOut = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
```

Try like this if you still have issues elaborate a bit more what the expected behavior is and through which means you are trying to get to that behavior

EDIT you also should set the callback path to something unique not an actual url in your webApp... cfr: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26932
Make sure that the callback path is also registered in your app registration on your AD these have to match

[image]

The actual redirect url where you wish to get after authentication should be set in the challenge! like so

```
//When login occurs we send the Scheme we wish to use when challenging and the redirect url we wish to be redirected to
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(authScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Content("~/") });
```

This would redirect back to root after authentication has been done in your middleware...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did change as per your suggestions. Still no luck. Now added events code and trying to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I m looking for, when my Home/Index page requested, Authenticate against Azure AD, redirect to Home/Dashboard.  it's a .Net Core project.

Comment: Solved my issue by setting callback path in appsettings to "/signin-microsoft" and
 in Azure AD, return URL set to https://localhost:44313/signin-microsoft. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thx could you accept my anwser as the correct one please thx!